Understanding spaces of negative regularity
I apologize if this question is too basic for this site, but I posted it on mathSE and did not get any responses (link can be found here) so I'm crossposting it here.
Let $C^k(\mathbb{R}^n$) be the space of functions with $k$ continuous derivatives, and $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the Sobolev space $W^{2,s}$. Their continuous dual spaces are commonly denoted as $C^{-k}$ or $H^{-s}$. Similar notations exist for duals to Holder spaces, Besov spaces...etc.
I had always thought the negative index was only notational, but it seems it has a genuine interpretation as "lacking regularity". For example, the space $C^{-k}$ can be seen as "lacking $k$ derivatives". And similarly, if I take the derivative of a $C^0$ function then the result is a distribution belonging to $C^{-1}$. How can one see this?
What justifies the interpretation that a space with index $-k$ "lacks $k$ derivatives"? Why are distributions/dual spaces the right setting for functions that lack some degree of differential regularity?

I would recommend you read through Section 14.3 of https://hairer.org/notes/RoughPaths.pdf which answers your questions (and more). It's five pages, it's self-contained (except maybe for a couple of definitions), and it uses only the definition of distributions and elementary calculus. Note that $C^{-k}$ is quite different from the dual of $C^k$ (think of $k=0$)...

I’d say the reason (say in one variable) relies in the fact that, first of all,  the distributional derivative  takes $C^0(I)$ to  its dual, and  for the rest,  it is  defined as  $-D^*$, so that  from  the derivative $C^{k+1}\to C^k$ you  still get  a derivative $C^{-k}\to C^{-k-1}$.

@MartinHairer Thank you very much!

@PietroMajer Sorry I did not fully understand the last part of your comment. Would you be able to explain how you get $C^{-k}\to C^{-k-1}$?

As $-D^:(C^{k})^\to (C^{k+1})^*$...

@PietroMajer Thank you.

@PietroMajer But don't forget that as mentioned above there is no natural convention under which $C^{-k}$ is the dual of $C^k$.

Yes, indeed I've never seen it before
